# Can only input one thing in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having a problem where I want the user to be able to input text to call functions. It works perfectly fine except for one thing. :/ Once something has been input nothing can be done afterwards. The only way to solve it is run the program again which is not convenient. I have spent a lot of time looking for an answer and need help. I also think other amateurs like me might be wondering this too.
An example of the code:

```
x = raw_input('test1')

if x == 'x':
    print 'test2'
```

The result:

```
test1x

test2

 x

'x'
```

As you can see it works once then stops working. For the record I'm using Python 2. Hope this can be solved :)

Comment: You have to write this code in a **loop**.

Comment: This question is about general programming fundamentals; this site is for solving problems, not teaching the basics.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a loop if you want to program to keep running.
Here is a simple example:

```
while True:
    n = raw_input("Please enter 'hello':")
    if n.strip() == 'hello':
        break
```

The program will keep running until you type hello

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function

```
def call():
    input = raw_input('input: ')
    if input == 'yes': 
         print 'yes'
    call()

call()
```

Comment: Not a good idea to implement with recursion

Answer (score 0):

```
last_data = ''
while last_data != 'yes':
    input = raw_input('ENTER SOMETHING: ')
    #do whatever you want with input

    last_data = raw_input('DO YOU WANT TO QUIT? (yes/no): ')
```